# How to develop with Marketing Cloud APIs?

Tags: authentication, marketing-cloud-connect

I'm working with a customer that has the MC connector installed. I'm wondering what is the best approach to start developing a custom Lightning Component that needs to integrate with a MC feature (sending SMS).

After thinking about it for a while, I think the approach would be to create a Lightning Component that has an Apex class as controller, which will make the connection with the MC REST API endpoints. The component must be customized because of the features wanted.

Now, regarding the authentication part, is there a way to create a user from outside MC? Or will I need to contact the customer, and tell them to create a user in MC for me, or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to get them to create an account for you in  the absence of an assigned API user. If they do have shared API credentials, then you can create Account users via SOAP.

Reference:

- [Create Account User SOAP Call](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/accountuser.htm)